# TestFX clickOn method is not recognized

Tags: java, testing, javafx, testfx

I built a simple calculator with JavaFX, now I want to test it and it is proving to be quite a challenge. I found out about a library called TestFX which seems to be perfect for testing my calculator. After adding the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>testfx-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.13-alpha</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>testfx-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.13-alpha</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

as stated in ther [GitHub repo](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX), however functions like **clickOn()**, **rightClickOn()**, **write()**, **push()** and so on... are not recognized like they are supposed to be as per the examples provided in their GitHub  repo.

[image]

Here are all my project dependencies:

[image]

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
public class CalcTDDTests extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent mainNode = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        mainNode.getStylesheets().add("styles/myStyles.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(mainNode));
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.toFront();
    }

    @Test
    public void testPressDigit() {
        clickOn("#nineBtn");
    }    

}
```

I am using NetBeans 8.2 and if this is a matter of importing some package, NetBeans is not finding it. I tried to import the following packages:

```
import static org.testfx.api.FxAssert.verifyThat;
import static org.testfx.matcher.control.LabeledMatchers.hasText;

import org.testfx.framework.junit.ApplicationTest;
import org.testfx.robot.Motion;
```

I'm using JDK 1.8 and JavaFX 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CalcTDDTests` extends `javafx.application.Application`. This class does not contain any of the methods you're looking for.

The class containing those methods is `org.testfx.framework.junit.ApplicationTest`. You need to extend this class instead of `javafx.application.Application`.

```
public class CalcTDDTests extends ApplicationTest {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Silly me, thank you so much! I need to wait 6 minutes to accept your answer.